# Ubuntu 19.10 - Night Mode does not change the color on screen

Tags: 19.10

after successfully using the Beta for a couple of weeks, I realized today, that in Ubuntu 19.10 Night Mode does not change the color of the video out put at all.
My configuration is a Dell Latitude E7440 using Intel graphics and Wayland session.

It always worked in 18.04, though....

Any Idea where to start looking for trouble shooting?

Comment: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/851

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### October 20, 2019

This was apparently fixed 4 days ago and should appear shortly in Ubuntu updates:

- [gamma ramp prediction broken for redshift-gnomerr](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/857)

The source code changed (if anyone cares) is here:

- [kms/crtc: Read gamma state when prediction failed](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/commit/1b4709794ea3602f5573fee164c880a14f049d3b)

### November 29, 2019

It's been reported in [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182266/ubuntu-19-10-night-mode-does-not-change-the-color-on-screen/1182446?noredirect=1#comment1995987_1182446) bug fix is now "live" in Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Saying "shortly" is rather misleading. I suggest you don't hold your breath. A non-priority fix is not going to land any time soon in ubuntu 19.10....

Comment: @solsTiCe I use my own Night Light / Redshift creation tailored to my multi-monitor environment so am personally not interested in getting a patch. Others could apply a patch if they didn't want to wait... correct?

Comment: I just switched back to Xorg

Comment: This is now live in Ubuntu 19.10.